# How many books hours does it take to replace motor 2001 Chevy blazer 4.3 L 4 x 4

Tags: engine, chevrolet, blazer, book-hours

How many books hours does it take to replace motor 2001 Chevy blazer  4.3 L 4 x 4

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: A word of caution: If by "book hours" you mean the time a shop will charge for a job, it would be of note that shopping related questions are off-topic. If you're wondering how long a job like that would take, I'd say that it could be highly-variable depending on the skill level of the workmen, the experience with that particular job, and the tools on-hand. Also, there is always the possibility of unforeseen problems adding hours to a job. I had a clutch that took ~5 hours of ridiculous wrestling because of damaged internals on top of the expected ~3 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Alldata says about 12.5 hours for a simple swap, and as much as 21.5 with transfer of components (aka "long block") and accounting for AC and a skid plate, if present.

Those numbers are for experts very familiar with the job, and does not include the various rusted and stuck "gotchas" that kyle_engineer hints at.

Believe me, they are there in force and plentiful.  Labor manuals are for setting baselines, usually in a dealership flat-rate environment.  Your mileage will Shirley vary...